# Malloc aborting with specific inputs

Tags: c, malloc

This is my first time posting here so I apologize if I'm not following the right etiquette. I also tried searching for answers but to no avail.

Basically, I have this function for a greedy coin change algorithm which takes as input some int. In my function I return a malloc'd array containing each coin. While it works for the most part, for some reason any coin value which produces 5, 9, ... (+4) coins as optimal distribution, ie, 9 would be (5 + 1 + 1 +1 + 1), or 650 which is 13 coins of 50 each, causes the program to abort with this message:

```
hello: malloc.c:2401: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && 
old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse 
(old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

However, every coin distribution that isn't 5 or 5+4+... works. Not sure what to do.

This is the function:

```
int* greedyAlg(int value)//computes and returns the optimal (minimum) number of denominations for a given value for US currency
    {
        //denominations
        int one = 1, five = 5, ten = 10, twenty = 20, fifty = 50;
        int x5 = 0, x4 = 0, x3 = 0, x2 = 0, x1 = 0;
        int count = 0;
        //int[] denom;

    while(value != 0)
    {
        if(value >= fifty)
        {
            value -= fifty;
            count++;
            x5++;

            /*while(value >= fifty)
            {
                // int *i = &fifty;
                value-=fifty;
                count++;
                x5++;
            }*/
        }
        else if(value < fifty && value >= twenty)
        {
            value -= twenty;
            count++;
            x4++;
        }
        else if(value < twenty && value >= ten)
        {
            value -= ten;
            count++;
            x3++;
        }
        else if(value < ten && value >= five)
        {
            value -= five;
            count++;
            x2++;
        }
        else if(value < five && value >= one)
        {
            value -= one;
            count++;
            x1++;
        }
    }
    //printf("Optimal denominations: ");
    int* denom = malloc(sizeof(int)*(count + 1));
    //int* denom = (int *)calloc(count + 1,sizeof (int));

    denom[0]=count;
    for(int i = 1; i<= (x5 + 1); i++){
        denom[i] = fifty;
    }
    for(int i= (x5 + 1); i<=(x5 + x4) + 1; i++){
        denom[i] = twenty;
    }
    for(int i = (x5 + x4) + 1; i <= ( x5 + x4 +x3 ) + 1; i++){
        denom[i] = ten;
    }
    for(int i = (x5 + x4 + x3) + 1; i <= (x5 + x4 + x3 + x2) + 1; i++){
        denom[i] = five;
    }
    for(int i = (x5 + x4 + x3 + x2) + 1; i <= (x5 + x4 + x3 + x2 + x1) + 1; i++){
        denom[i]=one;
    }
    return denom;
    free(&denom);
    //return count;
}
```

And this is how I'm printing it:

```
//prints elements of array created by (greedy) coin change algorithm
void printGreedyArr(int arr[], size_t count)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        printf("%s%d%s, ","[",arr[i],"]");
    }
    printf("\n%s %d\n","count was",count);
}
```

I call it with the 0th index which holds the length like so:

```
printGreedyArr(greedyAlg(x),greedyAlg(x)[0]);
```

(In my code I set up a loop with x as user input to test)

I can post any other relevant details if need be.

Comment: I haven't looked at the code in depth yet, but at first glance it looks as though you are freeing after returning in the algorithm function. You may want to fix that first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, however changing the loop condition to < as another commenter suggested worked. I'm still unsure of where to free the array though.

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem, without guessing about what your actual code looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `count` equals `x5+x4+x3+x2+x1`, you've got an off-by-one error:

```
for(int i=(x5+x4+x3+x2)+1; i<=(x5+x4+x3+x2+x1)+1; i++){
```

Should probably be:

```
for(int i=(x5+x4+x3+x2)+1; i<(x5+x4+x3+x2+x1)+1; i++){
```

Also similarly for the other `for` loops. Note the termination condition has changed from `<=` to `<`.

Also:

```
return denom;
free(&denom);
```

That `free()` will never be executed, and also the `&` should be removed from before the `denom` if you place it elsewhere.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. And I wasn't sure where to place the free(), but that makes sense.